# C# equivalent of Javas Guavas Maps.uniqueIndex

Tags: java, c#, refactoring

**Guava** has a static method

```
Maps.uniqueIndex(Iterable<V> values, Function<? super V,K> keyFunction)
```

which maps each entry in the entered collection by the result of the entered function applied on respective elements.

Is there any *analogues* for **C#** that do the same?

**Java** sample

`Map<String, Human> idToHuman = Maps.uniqueIndex(humans, Human::getPassportId)`;

Comment: Something like `var dictionary = values.ToDictionary(v => keyFunction(v));` where `values` implements `IEnumerable<V>`

Comment: If you could show some sample inputs and outputs for the Java, it may get you more results (since I don't know Java that well OTTOMH).

Comment: The `Function<? super V,K>` indicates supertype constraint which doesn't exist in C#. I understood that `Map` has `Dictionary` and `Iterable` has `IEnumerable` counterparts, but unable to figure out supertype constraint workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of `C#` where we have `IEnumerable<V>` instead of `Iterable<V>` and `Dictionary` insetead of `Map`. That's why we can put in C#

```
using System.Linq;

...

Dictionary<K, V> result = values.ToDictionary(v => keyFunction(v));
```

where `values` impelements `IEnumerable<V>` and `keyFunction` is `Func<V, K>`. In your case C# code can be something like this

```
using System.Linq;

... 

// I've turned Java getPassportId method into PassportId property 
// "Dictionary<String, Human>" declaration can be changed into just "var" 
Dictionary<String, Human> idToHuman = humans.ToDictionary(human => human.PassportId);
```